# Create Scrolling Event On Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, canvas

I have a popup with a canvas that displays a graph, but sometimes the graph is bigger than the canvas is there a way that I can add some sort of scrolling event to allow the user to scroll horizontally, to see the rest of the graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Canvas` is a normal DOM element like `img`, so you can use the regular CSS styles to define the scrolling behavior. For example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ctx = $("#canvs").get(0).getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';  
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,1600,300);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "lime";  
  ctx.moveTo(0, 150);      
  for (var i = 0; i <= 16; i++){
    var y = i % 2 == 0 ? 50 : 250;
    ctx.lineTo(i * 100, y);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
});
```

```css
#cont{
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 330px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='cont'>
  <canvas id='canvs' width='1600px' height='300px'></canvas>
</div>
```